Select Input not opening on touch -
I have a cam/presentation application.
In the whiteboarding tools (which open from bottom button on left tool bar), I cannot get the color picker or select fields to open on touchstart event, or any other combination I tried.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.
HT
<aside class="toolbar" id="toolbar">
    <!--All the tools and buttons to operate camera-->
    <h3>Tools</h3>
    <section class="tools-container">
        <button id="get-webcam" class="btn get-camera-btn tooltip-right"></button>
        <button id="invert-webcam" class="btn invert-camera-btn tooltip-right" disabled></button>
        <button id="get-display" class="btn get-display-btn tooltip-right"></button>
        <button id="make-whiteboard" class="btn make-whiteboard-btn tooltip-right"></button>
        <button id="get-mic" class="btn get-mic-btn tooltip-right"></button>
        
        <button id="whiteboard-tools-toggle" class="btn whiteboard-toggle-btn tooltip-top"></button>
    </section>
</aside>
<main id="main-container" class="main-container">
    <canvas id="main-canvas" class="main-canvas">
        <p>Update browser in order to use this Every Cam.</p>
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="whiteboard-canvas" class="whiteboard-canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="whiteboard-tools-wrapper">
        <section id="textbox-container" class="textbox-container">
            <input type="text" name="onscreen-text" id="onscreen-text" />
            <button id="text-place" class="btn text-place-btn tooltip-top">Place</button>
        </section>
        <section class="whiteboard-tools-container">
            <button id="pencil-tool" class="btn pencil-btn tooltip-top"></button>
            <button id="eraser-tool" class="btn eraser-btn tooltip-top"></button>
            <button id="text-tool" class="btn text-tool-btn tooltip-top"></button>
            <button id="line-tool" class="btn line-btn tooltip-top"></button>
            <button id="square-tool" class="btn square-btn tooltip-top"></button>
            <button id="ellipse-tool" class="btn ellipse-btn tooltip-top"></button>
            <input type="color" value="#257FD2" id="color-select" class="btn color-btn tooltip-top">
            <div class="color-style-wrapper tooltip-top">
                <select name="color-style-select" id="color-style-select" class="select-btn color-select-btn">
                    <option value="stroke">Stroke</option>
                    <option value="fill">Fill</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="size-select-wrapper tooltip-top">
                <select name="stroke-size-select" id="stroke-size-select" class="select-btn size-select-btn">
                    <option value="3">Small</option>
                    <option value="6">Medium</option>
                    <option value="9">Large</option>
                    <option value="12">XLarge</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button id="clear-whiteboard" class="btn clear-whiteboard-btn tooltip-top"></button>
        </section>
    </div>
    
</main>

ML
JS
const addFocus = (el)=>{
  el.focus();
}

this.textToolBar.textInp.addEventListener('input', e => {
  app.whiteboard.textTool.setText(e.target.value);
});
this.textToolBar.textInp.addEventListener('touchstart', ()=>{
  addFocus(this.textToolBar.textInp);
})

this.wbToolbar.colorSelect.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
  app.whiteboard.color = e.target.value;
  //console.log(e.target.value);
});
this.wbToolbar.colorSelect.addEventListener('touchstart', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.target);
  e.target.focus();
});

this.wbToolbar.colorStyleSelect.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
  app.whiteboard.shapeStyle = e.target.value;
  //console.log(e.target.value);
});
this.wbToolbar.colorStyleSelect.addEventListener('touchstart',(e)=>{
  console.log(e.target);
  e.target.focus();
});

this.wbToolbar.strokeSizeSelect.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
  app.whiteboard.strokeSize = e.target.value;
  //console.log(e.target.value);
});
this.wbToolbar.strokeSizeSelect.addEventListener('touchstart', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.target);
  e.target.focus();
});

I have tried prevent default, i've tried stop propagation.  I've tried forcing a click event on the touchstart.  I have other mouse and touch listeners which I've tried to do the same to in order to see if it is upstream.  No luck.

Why do you have your own event listeners instead of just using the built-in operation of the controls?

I have created a whiteboard on a HTML5 Canvas so that users can annotate on top of display and webcam sharing.  The buttons trigger class methods in the code.  Is there another way of doing it that would achieve the same results?

Solution found!  Answer was indeed in @barmar 's comment.  I had upstream watchers interfering.  I really need to put it all in one place, but I can't figure out how yet.  Future refactor, I'm sure.
I needed to remove the 'touchstart' event from the selectors and preventDefault on the 'touchend' for my other button watchers.
